# Por que loops são lentos no R? Como evitá-los?

Tags: r, loop

É muito frequente ouvir (ou ler) que os loops não são eficientes no `R`e devem ser evitados ([neste link](https://analisereal.com/2016/02/27/loops-no-r-usando-o-for-2/) ou [noutro link](http://r-br.2285057.n4.nabble.com/R-br-Funcionamento-implementacao-da-funcao-apply-lapply-em-loops-tp3595504p3596363.html) ou [mesmo neste](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-intro)).

E provar esta afirmação é simples:

```
numeros <- rnorm(10000)

com_loop <- function(vetor) {
  res <- 0
  for (i in seq_along(vetor)) {
    res <- res + vetor[i]
  }
  res
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  loop = com_loop(numeros),
  vetorizado = sum(numeros)
)

Unit: microseconds
       expr     min      lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
       loop 494.709 512.670 562.71062 514.723 551.9285 3074.480   100
 vetorizado   9.750  10.263  10.77702  10.264  10.2640   28.226   100
```

As perguntas que faço são:

1. Por que os loops são lentos no [r](/questions/tagged/r)?
2. Quais alternativas existem? (pacotes, estratégias, etc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excelente perguntas. Abaixo colocarei meus dois centavos a respeito delas.

**1. Por que os loops são lentos no R?**

Loops são lentos no R porque esta é uma característica intrínseca das linguagens interpretadas. Todo código escrito na linguagem R (que é uma linguagem interpretada como python ou ruby) é lido e *interpretado* para linguagem de máquina, para aí ser executado.

C, por outro lado, é uma linguagem compilada. Todo código escrito na linguagem C é compilado, transformado num executável na linguagem nativa do sistema operacional e processador da máquina e somente depois disso ele será executado.

Se fizermos um loop numa linguagem interpretada como o R, o passo de tradução do código escrito em R para a linguagem de máquina vai ocorrer para cada passo do loop. Assim, são adicionados vários passos extras na execução do programa, passos estes que não existem na linguagem compilada. E cada passo intermediário destes é somado ao tempo total de execução do programa.

Entendo que esta resposta talvez não responda diretamente a tua pergunta. Me deixe então refazê-la da seguinte maneira:

*Por que os loops no R são mais lentos do que o código vetorizado?*

Embora não pareça, a resposta para esta pergunta está na descrição que fiz acima. Muitos dos códigos nativos do R, como o `sum` do teu exemplo, foram escritos em C, C++ ou FORTRAN. Note o output que aparece no prompt quando digitamos `sum`:

```
sum
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

Esta função não foi escrita em R. Ela com certeza foi escrita em C, C++ ou FORTRAN, o que deixa a torna muito mais otimizada. Afinal, estas são linguagens compiladas, muito mais otimizadas para realizar quaisquer operações. Por isso a diferença de tempo de execução nos códigos `com_loop` e `vetorizado` do exemplo da tua pergunta.

**2. Quais alternativas existem? (pacotes, estratégias, etc)**

Basicamente, há três estratégias para tentar otimizar código no R. Entretanto, eles nem sempre funcionarão, pois cada caso é um caso.

1. Use código vetorizado

Por exemplo, funções da família `apply` possuem uma vantagem sobre loops. Muitas vezes (embora nem sempre), utilizar funções desta família vai deixar teu código mais rápido. Afinal, o R é uma linguagem que trabalha melhor com vetores. As funções da família `apply` utilizam esta característica do R de forma otimizada e, portanto, acabam sendo muitas vezes mais rápidas do que um `for` (ou `while` etc.).

Além de, *na minha opinião*, deixarem o código mais limpo e mais fácil de ser auditado posteriormente.

2. Paralelize o código

Utilize o poder do processamento em paralelo do teu computador. Em vez de usar um core para fazer o trabalho, distribua ele em mais cores. Os pacotes mais famosos para isto são o `parallel`, `doMC` e `foreach`.

Infelizmente, tentei no passado e nunca consegui fazer eles funcionarem no Windows. Desconfio, inclusive, que seja impossível. Entretanto, são facílimos de utilizar no macOS e Linux.

3. Leia o livro [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Ele traz muitas estratégias além destas duas que citei acima. O livro abriu meus olhos no passado, mostrando o que eu fazia de errado na hora de escrever meus códigos. São 9 estratégias bem mais detalhadas do que estas que coloquei aqui neste resumo e tenho certeza que muitas das tuas dúvidas serão esclarecidas por ele.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta do @Marcos Nunes, que está excelente, o texto que me fez entender a diferença entre loop e vetorização foi esse aqui: [Vectorization in R: Why?](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html)

O R é uma linguagem de alto-nível, ou seja, ele toma conta da interpretação do código por você. Por exemplo, quando você cria um código como este:

```
i<-5.0
```

Você não deve dizer para o computador:

1. que 5.0 é um número de ponto flutuante;
2. que o "i" deve guardar um dado de tipo numérico;
3. para achar um lugar na memória para o número 5;
4. registrar o "i" como um indicador para aquele lugar na memória.
5. que  precisa converter `i <- 5.0` para binário, pois isso é feito quando você clica enter;
6. se alterar valor de "i" para, por exemplo, `i <- "b"`, comunicar que o "i" não guarda mais um inteiro mas sim um caractere.

Quando você coloca isso dentro de um for, o R vai repetir esse processo de interpretação a cada loop. E é isso que torna o loop lento.

Por outro lado, se você coloca todos os valores num único vetor, esse processo de interpretação se dá de uma vez só, reduzindo assim o tempo de processamento. Daí porque vetores só aceitam um tipo de dado, ou seja, você não pode ter números inteiros, fatores e caracteres num mesmo vetor, pois isso romperia com a lógica de vetorização, que é realizar aqueles seis passos uma única vez.