# Diferenças e semelhanças entre funções apply e o for loop

Tags: r, for, apply

Tenho esta lista:

```
dataset<-data.frame(matrix(runif(6*30,20,100),ncol=6))
cluster<-kmeans(dataset,centers=3)
cluster
dataset$kmeans<-as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])
mylist<-split(dataset,dataset$kmeans)
names(mylist)<-paste0('dataset',seq_along(mylist))
```

Considere que eu queira saber o nome das variáveis presentes em cada um dos bancos de dados desta lista. Com `lapply`:

```
lapply(mylist,function(x){
  names(x)
})

#$dataset1
#[1] "var1"   "var2"   "var3"   "var4"   "var5"   "var6"   "kmeans"

#$dataset2
#[1] "var1"   "var2"   "var3"   "var4"   "var5"   "var6"   "kmeans"

#$dataset3
#[1] "var1"   "var2"   "var3"   "var4"   "var5"   "var6"   "kmeans"
```

Com `for` (sem `print`):

```
for(i in mylist){
  names(i)
}

# nada é emitido ao Console
```

com `for` (com `print`):

```
for(i in mylist){
  print(names(i))
}

#[1] "var1"   "var2"   "var3"   "var4"   "var5"   "var6"   "kmeans"
#[1] "var1"   "var2"   "var3"   "var4"   "var5"   "var6"   "kmeans"
#[1] "var1"   "var2"   "var3"   "var4"   "var5"   "var6"   "kmeans"
```

Além disso, é possível criar um objeto com `lapply`:

```
x<-lapply(mylist,function(x){
  names(x)
})
```

Mas com `for`, não:

```
x<-for(i in mylist){
  print(names(i))
}
```

Sempre pensei que a diferença entre `lapply` e `for` residisse apenas na *velocidade* de processamento, conforme mostra esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249786/por-que-loops-s%C3%A3o-lentos-no-r-como-evit%C3%A1-los). Mas, por estes detalhes já percebi que a diferença não é apenas esta.

Assim:

- quais as diferenças e semelhanças entre funções `apply` e `for` (a que se refere a construção dos blocos dentro destas funções)?
- por que devo usar `print` em `for` e, qual o motivo de não conseguir criar um objeto com ele da mesma forma que pode se fazer com funções `apply`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `lapply` vs `for`

`lapply` e `for` são funções primitivas no R. Sim, `for` é uma função primitiva também:

```
`for`(i, 1:10, {print(i + 1)})
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

- `for` recebe um nome de variável, uma sequência de valores e uma [expressão](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html) e avalia esta expressão modificando o valor da variável com o nome indicado para cada valor da sequência passada como argumento. O **importante** aqui é a palavra expressão. `for` avalia expressões.
- `lapply` recebe um vetor (no sentido de vetor em R de baixo nível, ou seja, qualquer coisa que pode ser criada usando `vector`) e uma função. Em seguida `lapply` aplica essa função para cada elemento do vetor passado como argumento e retorna os resultados em uma lista.

## por que preciso dar `print` dentro do `for`?

O `for` não retorna nenhum resultado. Ele apenas avalia a expressão que foi passada como argumento. Se essa expressão não *printar* nada no console, então o `for` não vai imprimir nada lá.

O `lapply` por si só também não imprime nada no console. O ponto é que `lapply` retorna uma lista com o resultado da aplicação da função para cada elemento de um vetor. Quando esse valor é retornado diretamente em sessões interativas, sem ser atribuído a uma variável, o R imprime esse valor no console. Por isso o seguinte funciona:

```
lapply(1:3, function(x) x)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

## por que posso criar objetos com `lapply` e não com `for`?

Como vimos anteriormente, `lapply` retorna uma lista. Se a função retorna uma lista, podemos atribuir um nome ao resultado. Isto é, podemos criar uma variável que salve os resultados.

```
x <- lapply(1:3, function(x) x)
```

Também vimos anteriormente, que o `for` não retorna nada. O `for` só avalia a expressão que passamos como argumento para cada valor possível da variável e do vetor que passamos como valores. Se o `for` não retorna nada, então não adianta salvar o resultado dele em uma variável. O que fazemos em geral é fazer o `for` avaliar expressões que salvam valores em objetos.

```
x <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)
for (i in 1:3) {
  x[[i]] <- i
}
```

## por que usar `for` ou `lapply`?

Em análise de dados, na maioria das vezes que queremos fazer loops é para aplicar a mesma função em cada elemento de um vetor. Neste caso ao invés de escrever:

```
x <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)
for (i in 1:3) {
  x[[i]] <- i
}
```

Que além de ser mais longo tem bem mais chance de ter algum erro, por exemplo esquecermos o índice. Em algum momento trocar o nome do índice e esquecer de mudar na expressão, etc.

Escrevemos:

```
x <- lapply(1:3, function(x) x)
```

Concorda que tem menos onde errar aí? Na verdade, é mais ou menos o mesmo motivo do porque usamos for ao invés de usar um `while` para fazer a mesma coisa:

```
x <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)
i <- 1
while (i <= 3) {
  x[[i]] <- i
  i <- i + 1
}
x
```

Tem muito mais onde errar, certo?
No fundo, trocamos um pouco de flexibilidade para ter menos lugares onde errar. O [capítulo](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-not) que o @JdeMello tem uma discussão interessante sobre quando usar `for`, `while` ou `lapply`.

## performance

É um mito no R de que `for` é muito lento quando comparado ao `lapply`. Na verdade `loops` são lentos em R quando comparados a códigos vetorizados. Para demonstrar isso considere o benchmark abaixo:

```
fun_lapply <- function(n) {
  lapply(1:n, function(x) x + 1)
}

fun_for <- function(n) {
  out <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    out[[i]] <- i + 1
  }
  out
}

fun_vet <- function(n) {
  as.list(1:n + 1)
}

bench::mark(
  fun_lapply(1000),
  fun_for(1000),
  fun_vet(1000)
) %>% dplyr::select(expression, min, mean, median, max)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  expression            min     mean   median      max
  <chr>            <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>
1 fun_lapply(1000)    302µs  328.3µs  319.1µs   2.33ms
2 fun_for(1000)      44.6µs   48.7µs   47.1µs   2.06ms
3 fun_vet(1000)        14µs     18µs   16.7µs   3.73ms
```

Veja como neste exemplo, `lapply` é muito mais lento que o `for` e a versão vetorizada é muito mais rápida do que os dois `loops`. Neste caso, conseguimos ver o overhead causado pelo `lapply` porque a função que estamos usando é muito simples, só uma adição. Na prática, a diferença entre `lapply` e `for` é mínima porque o que realmente vai custar é a função que está sendo executada no meio.

Portanto em conclusão para performance: use vetorização. Quando não puder, use `lapply` por que você terá muito menos chance de errar.

Answer (score 3):

## Semelhanças

A família `apply` é um [loop](/questions/tagged/loop) escondido. O código abaixo busca reconstruir sintaticamente a semelhança entre o `lapply` e um `for`.

```
resultado <- vector("integer", 10)
for (i in seq_along(resultado)) {
  resultado[[i]] <- i
}
resultado
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

resultado2 <- sapply(seq_along(resultado), function(i) {
  i
})
resultado2
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Outra semelhança entre o `for` e o `apply` é que ambas são funções (como tudo que "acontece"  no `R`).

```
class(`for`)
# [1] "function"
class(apply)
# [1] "function"
```

As diferenças começam quando verificamos as filosofias que dão base a estas duas funções.

## Diferenças

O `for` retorna `NULL` de forma invisível. Por esta razão, ele é pensado para efeitos colaterais. Dito de outra forma, o `for` é uma função que recebe como argumento os elementos com os quais ira interagir, executa um código no ambiente em que foi chamado para cada um destes elementos, e **sempre** retorna `NULL` invisível. Mais ou menos assim,

```
meu_for <- function(nome, iteradores, expr) {
  contador <- 1
  while (contador <= length(iteradores)) {
    assign(as.character(substitute(nome)), iteradores[contador])

    eval(substitute(expr))
    contador <- contador + 1
  }
  invisible(NULL)
}

meu_for(i, 1:10, {
  i
})
# Não imprime nada

meu_for(i, 1:10, {
  print(i)
})
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

Já a família `apply` está pensada de forma mais vinculada ao paradigma funcional, que tem aversão a efeitos colaterais. Isso faz com que elas busquem retornar um valor no lugar de esperar que você o faça por meio de efeitos colaterais.

## `print` e criação de objetos no `for`

A fato de o `for` sempre retornar `NULL` é a razão pela qual o loop não imprime e o apply imprime. Isso ocorre porque no `R` chamar um objeto no ambiente interativo é o mesmo que chamar `print(objeto)`. Porém no meio do corpo de uma função, chamar um objeto não imprime ele.

```
funcao <- function() {
  "Não me imprime"
  "Mas me imprime, porque sou o retorno da função"
}

funcao()
# [1] "Mas me imprime, porque sou o retorno da função"
```

Além disso, conforme a Jenny Bryan já disse, alguém provavelmente já escreveu um `loop` para você em funções como `base::lapply` ou `purrr::map`. A vantagem de confiar nestas formas é que

1. Você pode se aproveitar de melhorias e otimizações feitas por pessoas dedicadas a isso.
2. O código "dentro" do `loop` fica contido numa função e portanto pode ser testado e reutilizado mais facilmente.

Answer (score 1):

### Diferenças entre `lapply()` e `for`

*Este é um comentário não-exaustivo sobre esse tópico.*

<s>Realmente, `lapply` *tende* a ser mais rápido que `for` em [r](/questions/tagged/r). Isso por que `lapply()` é parcialmente escrito numa linguagem *low-level* (em [c](/questions/tagged/c)). *Under the hood*, se você checar `lapply`, você vai ver o seguinte:</s>

```
> lapply
function (X, FUN, ...) 
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
        X <- as.list(X)
    .Internal(lapply(X, FUN))
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000002dcc0e8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Quando chamamos `.Internal`, recebemos:

```
> base::.Internal
function (call)  .Primitive(".Internal")
```

Funções `.Primitive` são escritas em [c](/questions/tagged/c) e tendem a ser mais eficientes. Entretanto, elas são construídas de um modo diferente do que estamos acostumados com a sintaxe do `R`. Por isso que `lapply()` *tende* a ser mais rápido que o `for`.

Entretanto, tenha em mente que o `for` loop pode ser preferível à `lapply`, por exemplo quando você tiver que modificar parte de um objeto:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(num_1 = runif(100, 0, 100), 
           num_2 = rnorm(100, 100, 20), 
           char_1 = sample(letters, 100, replace = T), stringsAsFactors = F)

# modificar somente colunas numericas
cols <- grep(x= names(df), pattern = "(?i)^num", value = T)
```

Com `for`:

```
for(i in cols){
  df[[i]] <- round(df[[i]]) 
}
```

Com `lapply`:

```
invisible(
lapply(cols, function(x){
  df[[x]] <<- round(df[[i]])
})
)
```

Nesse caso, temos que usar `<<-` dentro de `lapply` para poder modificar `df` permanentemente. Além do mais, precisamos usar `invisible()` para evitar que o output de `lapply` saia no console.<sup>[1]</sup>

Além do mais, `for` permite certos control-flows como `next`:

```
for(i in seq_along(df)){

  if(is.character(df[[i]])) next # pular essa iteracao se condicao eh satisfeita

  df[[i]] <- round(df[[i]]) 
}
```

Se você quiser "criar" um object com `for`, você tem que criá-lo antes de começar o loop pois...

### por que devo usar `print` em `for` e, qual o motivo de não conseguir criar um objeto com ele da mesma forma que pode se fazer com funções `apply`?

`for` é um **loop** e não uma função que retorna um objeto. `apply` e suas combinações são funções que retornam objetos. Para se criar um objeto com `for`, é preciso definí-lo antes da iteração do `for` loop (usando o seu `mylist`):

```
x <- vector(length = length(mylist))
for(i in seq_along(mylist)){
  x[[i]] <- print(names(mylist)[[i]])
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "dataset1"
[1] "dataset2"
[1] "dataset3"
> x
[1] "dataset1" "dataset2" "dataset3"
```

<sup>[1]</sup> http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-not

Comment: não é verdade que o `for` é mais lento que o `lapply`.

Comment: Bem, na minha máquina, for loop é marginalmente mais lento, mas de fato o for loop melhorou muito nas ultimas edições do R e a diferença é imperceptível. Na verdade, na minha opiniao, o grande beneficio de lapply é o fato de não modificar objetos ja existentes no environment.

Comment: qual benchmark vc está fazendo?

Comment: Estou usando o pacote `microbenchmark`. Com um vetor com 100,00 elementos, a minha operação deu lapply mais rápido *na média*.